# Codeigniter: MySQL query - Distinct + Count

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need help getting this query to output what I want. I am trying to use distinct and count together, but I don't know how. Below is my order_item table and the code I am currently using.

```
   order_id |   product_carrier_link   |   Product_condition
   ------------------------------------------------
      5001         89                              1
      5001         89                              2
      5001         89                              1
      5001         89                              1
      5001         89                              1
      5001         89                              2
      5001         89                              2

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('order_item');
  $this->db->where('order_id', $id);
  $this->db->group_by('product_carrier_link');
  $this->db->group_by('product_condition');
  $this->db->distinct('product_condition');
  $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result();
```

This is resulting in the following

```
  order    product       condition
  5001        89           1
  5001        89           2
```

I need to count rows with product_condition 1 and product_condition 2. I want them to be displayed as qty. For instance:

```
  order    product       condition      qty
  5001        89           1             4
  5001        89           2             3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT is often considered as a special case of GROUP BY, [from the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html):

> For example, the following two queries are equivalent:
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1 WHERE c1 > const; 
> SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1 WHERE c1 > const GROUP BY c1, c2, c3;
> ```

in your case, you get the desired output like this (you don't need to use DISTINCT):

```
  $this->db->select('*, count( condition ) AS qty');
  $this->db->from('order_item');
  $this->db->where('order_id', $id);
  $this->db->group_by('product_carrier_link');
  $this->db->group_by('product_condition');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: you are welcome, if it helped you, you can "accept" this answer, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer